# getColumnDefs() method is not present in gridApi in ag- grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

I am trying to get column definition in ag grid in angular 10.
I am using below code using gridApi:

**console.log(this.gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs());**

But i am getting below error.

***Property 'getColumnDefs' does not exist on type 'GridApi'. Did you mean 'setColumnDefs'?***

even in gridApi.d.ts, getColumnDefs() method is not available.
But in ag grid documentation, it says this is the method.

[image]

i am using "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^24.1.0",
and angular 10.0.4.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

better to use separate varible for `gridAPI`

also we need to set up gridApi when Grid is ready.
I just run, and got all columns

```
    <ag-grid-angular
       .....
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

gridReadyEvent

```
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    console.log(this.gridApi.getColumnDefs()) 

    this.http
      .get('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }
```

Console log output:
[image]

AND DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/OmOxEfwFt02kBBvp